# (asp.net) Bootstrap 4 Navbar toggler not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 in asp.net (.net framework). When I change the website view to mobile view from pc view, the navbar-toggler-icon button is working. The navbar content is not showing when I press the toggler-icon button. the navbar-collapse id is same with the data-target, but it's still not working, Can you help me please. 
Here is my code:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.aspx">
            <img class="logo" src="img/Logo/logo_Rueston.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="navbar-collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/index.aspx">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rueston Water</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:Label>

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbSignup" runat="server" Text="SignUp"></asp:Label>

                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the demo picture:

[before pressing the toggler button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mymmv.png)

[After pressing the toggler button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNwLa.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `data-toggle="navbar-collapse"` in the button to `data-toggle="collapse"`

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Start on a blank page with no other css/html/js than the core boostrap files and paste your code with my change on it and see what happens. My guess is that something else is interferring.

Comment: I start a new project, bootstrap.min.css is only I use, but it's still not showing. Sad

Comment: You also need the bootstrap js file.